# Is it good practice to create Models directory?

Tags: laravel

By default, Laravel's model classes are placed in the App/ directory and models files mess up the App/ directory.
So, I want to create an App/Models/ directory and move all model classes to App/Models/.

And there are many articles in the internet and stackoverflow answers about how to do that.

My question is whether it is a good practice or bad practice to move models to App/Models/ in Laravel?

Laravel doesn't do it by default, so I think it should be a very bad practice because it is said that Laravel gives developers the best practices, and I'm afraid that moving models to App/Models/ causes troubles in the future while developing.

If it is a good practice, why doesn't Laravel do it by default?

Comment: in L8, models are on `App/Models` directory..it's completely okay if you want to move your models in a directory.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: @zahid thank you. that is good news. I hope my next project use L8.

Comment: The word, bad practice, in this question means causing some troubles or bugs. And good practice doesn't cause any trouble. Nothing to do with opinion-based.

Comment: @A.ANoman in the last project, I used probably version 5, which locates models in App/. I hope my next project will use version 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not quite right. Since Laravel 8, the models can be found under App/Models. And I think it's better that way.

Comment: it should a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I thought about that for a moment too. But it's the answer to the question, so in this case I went for the answer. But in principle I agree with you.

Comment: @MaikLowrey thank you for the answer. It's a useful answer for me and those who still don't know Laravel finally stores model files in Models/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely okay to do like that. Always I create separate folders for Frontend, backend controllers also. In Models also you can do as per you wish. Only thing is you have to define namespace depend on that.